# Making a dynamic Form in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

[What I want to achieve Image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOQW7.png) Hi I am working on a module in prestashop. What I want is that there should be a button (any-name: Add new field) in the backoffice-(Module Configuration page the first page that comes when you configure your module) that the user presses and it should add a new input field in the form. This all should be done using the helper classes. How can I achieve that? Some code would be grateful! I have uploaded an image. I have tried it using jQuery and it works but I need this done using helperForms in prestashop! In jQuery if I press the add new field button it adds an input field dynamically but the helper-classes are not used in that case.

Comment: Your module is a form builder ? what is the purpose of this form ? I ask because i also want to use helper class in order to handle custom datas in a module and i’m not sure it is possible with helper classes (when i read documentation i understand it is only possible with module configuration and prestashop object in backoffice (customer, orders, etc.), see the documentation quote in my answer.

Comment: Yes it is a form builder just to allow the user to add as many input fields as he wants.

Comment: ok, but add `input` field to what ? contact form ? product ? What do you think of my last comment ? Is it possible to use helper classe to do that ? I’m not sure.

Comment: I want to add input field to helperForm not contact Form or product specifically, but to my module's helperForm class.

Comment: I haven't accomplished it yet. But that's my goal.

Comment: In that case, it's easy, see my example code in my answer, it works ;-) but you should know that this helper (`HelperForm`) is used to generate an edition form for an object of type ObjectModel. Example: editing the client's profile.

Comment: Your code only adds one text input and a submit button. It is not dynamic. What I mean to say that it is fixed. User will only get one input text field. The user on runtime should be able to add this code dynamically meaning add how many input fields on the click of a button.

Comment: Ha i finally understand. That’s why you should be very clear in you question ! So, i really don’t know if it is possible because helper classes are used in your module class so maybe there is no way to add them dynamically. When you click on "new fields", you add the field with ajax ou you reload the page ?

Comment: currently as I have done in the image shown I have used configure.tpl and back.js (in which I have written the jQuery code to add a simple input field and attached it to a div in configure.tpl)

Comment: I don't use ajax currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the documentation :

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+Helper+classes

the documentation is for PS 1.6 but it should also work with PS 1.7

Here is an example of code that generate a form with Helper Classes :

```
$this->fields_form = array(
  'legend' => array(       
    'title' => $this->l('Edit carrier'),       
    'image' => '../img/admin/icon_to_display.gif'   
  ),   
  'input' => array(       
    array(           
      'type' => 'text',
      'name' => 'shipping_method',
     ),
  ),
  'submit' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Save'),       
    'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'   
  )
);
```

I don’t know if you can use Helper class for custom forms that update custom datas. I’m sure you can use them to update module configuration and prestashop object (customer, etc.)

> Helper classes enable you to generate standard HTML elements for the
>   back office as well as for module configuration pages.

Comment: Hi why the minus on my question :(. And the code you have written. I know that but that is not what I required. I want make a form dynamically in the backoffice.

Comment: I’m not responsible for the down vote but i think it is because your question is unclear (what exactly are you trying to do) and you didn’t show what you have tried so far. It is like this on stackoverflow : you need to show the code you are trying to implement and describe precisely your issue. So you should edit you question otherwise it could be closed by the community.

Comment: Hi, I have update the question. I hope it's clear :)

Comment: What I want to do is make a button that gets input fields dynamically in prestashop backoffice using helperClasses. I have achieved it using jQuery but I want to do this using the helperForm that we normally use in the backOffice in prestashop.